# using mysql concat and searching for that field using like, does that work?

Tags: mysql, concatenation, sql-like

I am creating a query like the following

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.firstName," ",u.lastName) as user
```

then later on in the query I write:

```
WHERE user LIKE '%jay%'
```

I am getting no results.  Are you not able to use a concatenated field this way?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.firstName," ",u.lastName) as user ... WHERE user LIKE '%jay%'
```

will not work, but

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.firstName," ",u.lastName) as user ... HAVING user LIKE '%jay%'
```

will work, as `HAVING` works on the results of the query, whereas `WHERE` does not.